# How to move a file based on a keyword in it through a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I need to move some XML files from one directory to another based on whether a particular string is present in it or not(i.e. if the string is present then move, else keep it). Is it possible to do so using a batch script?

Comment: is the string to be checked in the file or just the file name ? Can you use powershell, it will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should copy the files with `string` in the filename.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.xml /b /a-d ^|find /i "string" ') do copy "%%a" "d:\new\folder"
```

Comment: Well, if the keyword is meant to be in the name then perhaps it would be better to do just `COPY *string*.xml "targetpath"`.

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, that will work just as well.  It was meant to be `move` I noticed later.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FINDSTR` like this to move file `fred` if it contains the word "`hello`":

```
findstr hello fred
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
   echo Move that puppy
)
```

If you want to search insensitive to case (lowercase vs uppercase) use `FINDSTR /I`

Powershell is not available on all Windows versions, by the way, whereas this is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using windows server 2003. Powershell is most probably unavailable here.

Comment: Ok, so hopefully this is the correct way to go for you (as this is not Powershell).